# Is BitCoin developer page's HD Wallet image wrong

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, hardened-derivation

Here is the image I copied from the https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/wallets.html#id9

What I understand is that `M/0'/1'` can derive `M/0'/1'/0`.
`M/0'/1'` can't derive `M/0'/1'/0'`.

To derive `M/0'/1'/0`, we don't need `m/0'/1'`. To derive `M/0'/1'/0'`, we need `m/0'/1'`

Am I right? Or Is the Image right?

[image]

Comment: Everything you said sounds correct, but I don't see what is wrong with the diagram.

Comment: @PieterWuille 
The diagram does not draw an arrow from `M/0'/1'` to `M/0'/1'/0`. There should be an arrow there.

Comment: You are correct.